# (C++) How to redefine "=" operator for object

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, redefine

I have an object of class A.

```
class A[
{
   int x;
   string y;
   float z;
    ....
}
```

Then I have an int, called "integer".
How can I redefine the = operator in order to do something like

```
int integer;
A obj = integer;
```

in order to obtain something equal to the constructor call with NOT all members:

```
A obj(integer,",0);
```

Comment: Provide your own `operator=(int)`.

Comment: `A obj = integer;` calls a constructor, never `operator=`. `A obj; a = integer;` would call `operator=`.

Comment: @iBug how can I do it? this is the question

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I modified the question, x is not the only member of class.

Comment: @Bibby2881 It doesn't matter. `A obj = integer;` still calls constructor, not assignment operator. Of course, you can provide both for your class.

Comment: The *specific* how-can-I question with the above "code" doesn't need an assignment operator overload; it needs a *conversion constructor* (and possibly a copy-constructor at least declared, even though the latter can/will be elided).

Comment: `A(int x_) : x{x_} { }` will allow `A obj = integer;` but since `integer` has not been initialized, it's sort of a train wreck beforehand.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I get this error: no viable conversion from 'int' to 'A'

Comment: Until your question is updated to reflect *real* code that is producing the error you're stating, whatever you're getting is irrelevant. To accomplish what you *seem* to be asking [requires a conversion constructor](https://godbolt.org/z/8jsMP5KWd). If that is not sufficient for your needs, then we need to see a properly configured [mcve] .

Answer (score 0):

This is a little naughty, but:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
public:
    int x;

    A & operator=(int value) {
        x = value;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int, char **) {
    A obj;

    obj.x = 5;
    cout << "Initially: " << obj.x << endl;

    obj = 10;
    cout << "After: " << obj.x << endl;

}
```

When run:

```
g++ Foo.cpp -o Foo && Foo
Initially: 5
After: 10
```

Is this what you're trying to do? Note that this is very naughty. class A is NOT an integer, and assigning it to an int is going to confuse people. C++ lets you do things that you probably shouldn't do, and this is one of them.